# Make Ubuntu Server Accessible to the Internet

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, ubuntu-server

I have just installed the latest version of Ubuntu server, php, Apache, Shorewall and MySQL.

The problem is that I can't access the website from other computers. I read that to fix that I need to change the DMZ or Port Forwarding. I'm not sure how to do that; which document to change or what.

Also the problem is that I live on an apartment complex where internet access is included. I just plug the ethernet cable to the wall and I register on a time warner "HiSpeedUp" page and then I get the internet working. So I don't know how to check the router information or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your apartment building is giving public IPs to its residents(unlikely), you will not have access to forward ports to your linux computer.

Answer (score 3):

Check with the apartment manager.  It may violate the TOS to run a public webserver on that connection.  If not, he may be willing to forward a port to your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a home network consists of an internal computer(s) connected to a router or gateway, which connects to the ISP, then the world.  In a logical sense, once you get outside the router or gateway, you're visible to the world.  So, you would need to access the router or gateway and forward ports from your specific machine's internal IP address to the world.  There's really 3 steps that makes this an efficient setup:

1. An internal reserved or static IP so the forward rule always works.
2. A rule to forward the ports you need through the router to the world.  If you're running a web server, then just 80 would suffice.
3. A dns name pointing to your machine.  Since your public IP address (the one your ISP provides you) is likely not static, you need a way to update your DNS name if your IP address changes.  [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com) is the easiest way to do this.

In your specific setup, it sounds like you don't have access to your router or gateway, so it likely won't work.  I second the "get external hosting" option.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is going to be something you'll end up making happen. Aside from the obvious (your landlord will need to work with you to get this working.. not likely). In the event you prove me wrong, however, please post back here. :) Always love a good success story. :P

If you're interested in working with a relatively blank, publicly accessible linux box, I'd recommend you try a host like Slicehost. $20 / mo will get you a decent server to muck around with, and you will have full control over what is and is not installed (it's a blank box). Not to mention, by outsourcing the hardware / connection, you rid yourself of any number of headaches that would otherwise be unavoidable.